# React Native 0.63 build fails due to bugsnag

Tags: android, react-native, bugsnag

The build just says:

`Build file '/.../node_modules/@bugsnag/react-native/android/build.gradle' line: 17`

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':bugsnag_react-native'.
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)
```

The mentioned line is just `apply plugin: "kotlin-android"`

we're just adding it to the project and following https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/react-native/#installation

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and what fixed it for me was updating the Kotlin version in `android/build.gradle` to `1.3.72`.

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    ...
    ext.kotlinVersion = '1.3.72'
  }
   ...
```

This SO answer helped me figure out what the problem was: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62475745